# PHP form post utf-8

Tags: php, forms, utf-8

everybody! I need to set up the utf-8 encoding in PHP code. Could you help me, please.

```
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));
$to = 'mail@mail.com'; 
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@mail.com\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: As an aside, there's really not much point running `strip_tags` on top of `htmlspecialchars`